# Custom Object Field Name Values Are Not Stored or Not Available As Referenced Data in Lookup?

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

We have three custom/standard objects (Opportunity, Package__c, Economics__c) referencing somehow Plant__c.

Upon creation of Plant__c,

```
public static Plant__c createTerminal(String country){
  Plant__c terminal = new Plant__c();
  terminal.Country__c = country;
  terminal.Name = 'Batangas Terminal';
  insert terminal;
  return terminal;
}
```

or even

```
public static Plant__c createTerminal(String country){
  Plant__c terminal = new Plant__c(Name='Batangas 
  Terminal',Country__c=country);
  insert terminal;
}
```

and then we use this as reference:

```
//Under Opportunity-related logic; Supply_point__c: Lookup(Plant)
public static Opportunity createOpportunity(Station__c statnObj, 
   Account accountObj, Plant__c terminalObj, string country){
   Opportunity oppoObj = new Opportunity();
...
   oppoObj.Supply_point__c = terminalObj.Id;
...
}

//Under Package__c-related logic; Terminal__c: Lookup(Plant)
public static Package__c createPackage(User userObj,Opportunity oppoObj,boolean bulkBAR,string country){
   Package__c packageObj = new Package__c();
...
   packageObj.Terminal__c = oppoObj.Supply_point__c.Id;
...
}

//Under Economics__c-related logic; Package__c: Lookup(Package)
public static Economics__c createEconomics(User userObj,Package__c packageObject,string COT,string version){
   Economics__c economics = new Economics__c();
...
   economics.Package__c = packageObject.Id;
...
}
```

But during testing/debugging, all the IDs are correct and referenced correctly. But, the Plant__c.Name does not get retrieved at all; it's just a dash. And, the Plant__c.Country field is not even there.

```
Name:-
Id:<alphanumeric>
```

```
Package__c terminalId;
terminalId = [SELECT Terminal__c from Package__c b WHERE b.Id=:econ.Package__c LIMIT 1];
//Successful retrieval of data.
System.debug('SOQL Terminal__c: ' + terminalId.Terminal__c + '\nSOQL Terminal Id: ' + terminalId.Id);
Plant__c terminalName = [SELECT Name From Plant__c p WHERE p.Id =: terminalId.Terminal__c];
//Unsuccessful. Only contains Id; no name, no country.
System.debug('SOQL Terminal Name: ' + terminalName);
```

Am I doing something wrong with the declaration and referencing?

Comment: I feel like there's some important context here that you haven't shown us. Please [edit] your question to show us a more complete and syntactically correct snippet of your code.

Comment: About the best thing I can come up with for this right now is that Salesforce displaying the name of the related record when you look at it in the web UI is just a UX (user experience)/quality of life thing. The relationship is actually an Id behind the scenes. If you want to get the related record's name, you need to actually query for the name (set the relationship field on an object, dml insert/update, then query for the object like `[SELECT Id, Supply_Point__r.Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = <some id>]`)

Comment: hi @DerekF, I've updated the code. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug on how the Plant__c object is created. There might be some automation (i.e. trigger, flow, workflow rule, etc.) that might be causing the Name value to be overwritten to dash.